# At what elevation is the airfield considered a high elevation field for takeoff and landing for 737-8?

Tags: boeing-737, high-altitude

At what elevation is the airfield considered a high elevation field for takeoff and landing for 737-8 ?

Comment: I don't believe there's a distinct threshold that anyone calls "high elevation."  There's a smooth continuum from at-or-below sea level, up to whatever altitude the manufacturer has determined is elevation where there's no longer a practical market demand.  There's not a magic weight, temperature, pressure, or field elevation that would officially start "high elevations."  I either have enough runway and climb gradient (including constraints for engine out situations) or I don't.

Comment: @MaxR great one, thank you.